# How to filter a word using array.filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, properties

I simply want to know how to return the indexes of the objects whose name property is equal to "Bob" using the filter method. (in this case one Index for simplicity)

data.json

```
[
 {
    "index": "14",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "23",
  },
  {
    "index": "23",
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30",
  },
  {
    "index": "17",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "25",
  },
]
```

app.js

```
const data = require("./data.json");


const searchword = "Bob";
const result = data.filter((word) => ???word === searchword???);
console.log(result);
```

Should show index:14,17

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as a `filter` and a `map`

```js
const data = [
 {
    "index": "14",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "23",
  },
  {
    "index": "23",
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30",
  },
  {
    "index": "17",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "25",
  },
]

const searchWord = "Bob";
const result = data.filter(x => x.name == searchWord) // find by searchWord
                   .map(x => x.index); // get the index
console.log(result.join(",")); // result is an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` method

```js
const data = [
  {
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    age: "23",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    age: "30",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Bob",
    age: "25",
  },
];

const getIndexes = (arr, word) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, { index, name }) => (name === word ? acc.concat(index) : acc),
    []
  ).toString();

console.log(getIndexes(data, "Bob"));
```